# Detect the resize of a div with query?

Tags: jquery

i wrote this little function:

```
function tester(){
var height = $("#master").height();
$("#slave").css("height", height);
}

tester();
```

How can I check if the `#master` size changed, it is a tab and may vary in size.

Thx for your help

Comment: As a note: `It works when i resize the window,`  It wont work if you resize a window, it has to be `$(window).resize(tester);`, if you write `tester()` then it will be called immediately.

Comment: @t.niese right, thanks.  it has to be called immediately anyways. but thanks for advise.

Comment: But because `tester` does not return anything your code is equal to write `tester(); $(window).resize(undefined);`. So the `$(window).resize` has not effect in your code. So you statement `It works when i resize the window` is wrong.

Comment: @t.niese yes. i just got that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call `tester()` whenever a tab change is triggered. That should give you the height of `#master` element.